# shader tutorial for unity

Tags: unity, shaders

I would like to start developing my own shaders within unity.

For starters I would like to do a screen spaced blur.

Are there any good tutorials to learn shader development besides the official unity documentation, which i find a bit hard to understand?

Comment: probably better to ask on http://answers.unity3d.com/ it's like Game Development but just for unity.

Comment: @David the signal/noise ratio on Unity Answers has gotten pretty bad.  Here's probably a better resource: http://forum.unity3d.com/forums/16-ShaderLab

Comment: Jessy did a complete set of Unity iOS Shader tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/user/JessyUV#grid/user/31F6A116DCCC9F61

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity.
The tutorials are organized in an increasing difficulty order and each was written with Unity in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Easy to understand tutorial

- http://virtualautonomy.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/31/tutorial-2-an-introduction-to-shaders-in

And the following wiki book helped me much

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Unity/Minimal_Shader

Don't forget Jessy's video tutorials

- http://www.youtube.com/user/JessyUV#grid/user/31F6A116DCCC9F61

And some Unity3D resources really helped me to build up the basics

- http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-Reference.html
- http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Shaders.html
- http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ShaderTut1.html
- http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ShaderTut2.html